# Prove that $f(x,y)=(x+2y+y^2+|xy|,2x+y+x^2+|xy|)$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> Define $f:\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R^2; ~~~(x,y)\longrightarrow(x+2y+y^2+|xy|,2x+y+x^2+|xy|)$
>
> Prove that $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$.

In order to prove that $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ we must have
$\lim _{|h|\to 0}\dfrac{|f(h)-f(0)|}{|h|}= 0$

But here $\lim_{h^2+k^2\to 0}\dfrac{h+2k+k^2+|hk|}{h^2+k^2}$ does not exist.

Is my approach wrong? Or the problem? Please help.

Comment: Where did you get that limit expression? Remember you need to show that $\frac{|| f(h, k) - f(0, 0) || }{||(h, k)||} \to 0$ as $h, k \to 0$ together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ if and only each of its components are differentiable at $(0,0)$. If $f_1$ denotes the first component, then, you have to compute:

- $$L_1 = \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x} (0,0)$$
- $$L_2 = \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y} (0,0)$$

Then, $f_1$ is differentiable iff:

$$\lim_{(h,k) \to (0,0)} \frac{f_1(0+h,0+k) - f_1(0,0) - L_1h - L_2 k}{\|(h,k)\|} = 0$$

The same thing is to be done with $f_2$.

Comment: But  here limit is $1$ when I consider $f_2$ so why is $f$ differentiable

Comment: $L_1=2;l_2=1 $ for $f$

Comment: @Amartya I don't quite understand. Did you follow these steps? And what did you obtain? I just did the calculations and the required limits were $0$.

Comment: You are right. Regarding $f_2$, $L_1$ and $L_2$ are respectively $2$ and $1$. But the limit that determines differentiability is equal to $0$.

Comment: Can you please show the calculations for $f_2$;I am getting it as 1

Comment: $\lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)}\dfrac{h^2+|hk|}{h^2+k^2}$;Putting $h=r\cos\theta;k=r\sin\theta$

Comment: the limit is coming as1

Comment: @Amartya, you forgot the square root over $h^2 + k^2$.

Comment: Oh yes;thank you